# duplicate symbol error when add a 3rd library for arm6

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got the following error when add a 3rd party library:`UMSNSLibrary.a`

Please help, thanks!

> " ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_UMSNSJsonParser.c in /Users/macbookpro/Downloads
>       /UMSNSLibrary.a(UMSNSJsonParser.o) and /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/HeXuanDemo EN/Build/Products/Debug-
>       iphoneosbThree20UI.a(UMSNSJsonParser.o) for architecture armv6 "

Answer (score 0):

Simply try to delete file form one of the Location you don't need:
either from

```
 /Users/macbookpro/Downloads /UMSNSLibrary.a(UMSNSJsonParser.o)
```

or  `/Users/macbookpro/Downloads/HeXuanDemo EN/Build/Products/Debug- iphoneosbThree20UI.a(UMSNSJsonParser.o)`

Clean the build and reset simulator and launch again.
I think it will resolve this.

Comment: after I remove UMSNSLibrary.a to desktop from : /Users/macbookpro/Downloads /, clean and build, there is such error: "  /Users/macbookpro/Downloads /UMSNSLibrary.a : no such file or directory" . thanks. Sorry, just got time to test your method.

Comment: ok .. then lets try  removing from other location from Downloads/HeXuanDemo EN/Build/Products/Debug- iphoneosbThree20UI.a?

Comment: sorry, but I didnot find the Debug- iphoneosbThree20UI.a in the path: Downloads/HeXuanDemo EN/Build/Products/ .

Answer (score 0):

Target->Build Setting->Header Search Path / Library Search Path : Remove unwanted path from there.